# Facebook like button in sencha architect

Tags: facebook, extjs, sencha-touch-2, facebook-like, sencha-architect

I have a problem with a facebook like button.
In the facebook developer, facebook give us 3 differents methods to integrate the like button in our app. In this example I use all the 3 methods.

I have created 3 buttons in sencha architect touch (Ext.Button). After I have created a basic function where I pass to the HTML buttons config the 3 methods:

`var me = this,
        htmlStrBase,
        htmlStr,
        htmlStrBase1,
        htmlStr1,
        htmlStrBase2,
        htmlStr2;`

```
htmlStrBase = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tecnitalia?ref=ts&fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>';
htmlStrBase1 = '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/tecnitalia?ref=ts&fref=ts&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=838403862859130" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
htmlStrBase2 = '<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/tecnitalia?ref=ts&fref=ts" layout="button" action="like" show_faces="false" share="false"></fb:like>';

me.getLikebutton().setHtml(htmlStrBase);
me.getLikebutton1().setHtml(htm

lStrBase1);
me.getLikebutton2().setHtml(htmlStrBase2);
```

naturally first I have launched the FB.Init (for the desktop and for the App):

`if(Ext.os.is.Android || Ext.os.is.iOS) {`

```
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status     : true,
        nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
        useCachedDialog: false,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    //alert('dopo FB.init');
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        //alert('status changed');
    });

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXX&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

}
//Otherwise let's use the the web version
else
    {
        //Wait for sdk to load
        //alert('eseguo fbAsyncInit');
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

            FB.init({
                appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                status     : true,
                xfbml      : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                //alert('status changed');
            });
        };

        //alert(' after fbAsyncInit e now include SDK');
        //Include SDK

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
```

the final result is that on the desktop, it functions perfectly but on my android App not yet...I Don't see any like button.

I say you last thing....if I copy one of this 3 methods directly in the html button config I can see the like button on my App. But I cannot copy directly this methods in the HTML config button because I need to change the facebook address each time a user logged in my App.

Somebody can help me and knows a method to integrate in my app the like button dinamically?
thank you
Carlo

Hi Guillard. Thank's. It's function but I have another problem. in android After the Like Login It show me a blank page!!!! No with mozilla or Firefox on desktop.
Thank you
Carlo

Answer (score 0):

One thing that made a difference for me was adding the Facebook Scripts after my panel with `fb-root` id was already in place.

Here I created a `Container` with a bottom toolbar and a another container (fb-root) that has a Like button for the Sencha page.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    html : 'My Sencha touch panel',
    items: [
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Sencha Touch',
        },{
            docked: 'bottom',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui: 'light',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                id: 'fb-root',
                width: 50,
                height: 20
            }]
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        initialize : function (container) {
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            var html = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/senchainc" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>';
            container.query('toolbar container')[0].setHtml(html);
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cmm

Comment: thanks Guilherme...Can you see my post below your reply? I have a problem

Comment: There is no need to query your component. just change the last line to: `container.setHtml(html);`. And please, erase your answer, this is not how you are supposed to ask further questions.

Comment: Hi Guillard. Thank's. It's function but I have another problem. in android After the Like Login It show me a blank page!!!! No with mozilla or Firefox on desktop.
Thank you
Carlo